# Why am I getting" invalid as a react child" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm encountering an error in React saying 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})'. This occurs during the rendering phase, where React is expecting elements or an array of elements but is instead receiving an object. The error trace includes functions like reconcileChildFibers, updateHostComponent, and performUnitOfWork. How can I resolve this issue so that React correctly renders the intended components or data?

I think the issue is with the below code:

```
import React from "react";
const Select = ({ name, label, options, error, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <select {...rest} name={name} id={name} className="form-control">
        <option value="" />
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option._id} value={option._id}>
            {option.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

I removed the {} from the map function hoping it would resolve the issue but it did not.

Comment: how does `options ` data look like? can u add it in question?

Comment: We can't see your data. But what you should be looking for is whether `label`, the `name` of each option, or `error` are objects.

Comment: Hope some of your parameters in Select funtion is an object, try consoling the parameters. And if the options parameter is an object directly use `options._id` and remove map method